# GStreamer: no element

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspbian, gst-launch

I am trying to run UDP streaming from a Raspberry Pi 4, and have installed gstreamer using this, found on gstreamer's docs:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools \
gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

Moreover, I have installed x264 and v4l-utils. However, when trying to execute commands such as

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc
$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src
```

It fails with error

```
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "videotestsrc"
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "v4l2src"
```

Some answers on previous posts have been to run `gst-inspect-1.0 videotestsrc`, which always gives me `symbol lookup error: gst-inspect-1.0: undefined symbol: GST_CAT_DEFAULT`, no matter what input.

I have also tried running `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib` and `sudo ldconfig`, with no success.

Reinstalling Gstreamer entirely has been no success so far. Any ideas?